# Prove that $|Conj_N(n)|$ divides $|Conj_G(n)|$ if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

If $G$ is a finite group, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. $n\in N$ .Denote the conjugacy class of $n$ in $G$ as $Conj_G(n)$ and the conjugacy class of $n$ in $N$ as $Conj_N(n)$. Prove that $|Conj_N(n)|$ divides $|Conj_G(n)|$.

$\textbf{My attempt}:$

I try to consider $N$ acts on $Conj_G(n)$ by conjugation, and I notice that $|Conj_N(n)|$ is one of the orbits. I can only get $|Conj_N(n)|=|N|/Z_N(n)$, but I can't get any further...

Any help will be appreciated,thanks!

Comment: A general hint: if group $G$ acts *transitively* on (nonempty) set $A$ and $H \trianglelefteq G$ is a normal subgroup, then $G$ acts canonically on the quotient set $A/H$ (the set of orbits under $H$), since for any $\lambda \in G$ and any $X \in A/H$ one also has $\lambda X\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\left\{\lambda x\right\}_{x \in X} \in A/H$. Furthermore, try to see why the transitivity of the original action of $G$ on $A$ entails the transitivity of the canonical action of $G$ on $A/H$ and - subsequently - why this property entails the fact that any two orbits under $H$ are equipotent.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ: I couldn't understand the last statement... How does the transitivity helps to prove orbits under $H$ are idempotent?

Comment: Not *idempotent* (a notion that doesn't make sense for arbitrary sets), but **equipotent**: one says two given sets $X$ and $Y$ are equipotent if there exists a bijection between them, so this is merely a synonymous way of saying the two sets have equal cardinality. If I find the time later during the week I might try to write a neat, detailed answer but let me not make any definite promise for I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to try and supply you with an answer, which - in order to be made clear - will require that you try to walk together with me through some preliminary notions and results:

1. Given an arbitrary set $A$ let us write $\mathscr{P}(A)$ for its powerset. We call $\mathscr{R}$ a **partition** of $A$ if the following conditions are satisfied:

   - $\mathscr{R} \subseteq\mathscr{P}(A) \setminus \{\varnothing\}$ ($\mathscr{R}$ consists of *nonempty* subsets of $A$)
   - for any two members $X, Y \in \mathscr{R}$ we have $X \neq Y \Rightarrow X \cap Y=\varnothing$ (two distinct members are necessarily disjoint)
   - $\displaystyle\bigcup \mathscr{R}=A$, in other words $A$ is equal to the union of all the members of $\mathscr{R}$.

   We shall write $\mathscr{Part}(A)$ for **the set of all partitions** of $A$.
2. Consider an arbitrary action of a group $G$ on a set $A$; for arbitrary subsets $\Lambda \subseteq G$ and $X \subseteq A$ we shall write $\Lambda X\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\{\lambda x\}_{\substack{\lambda \in \Lambda \\ x \in X}}$ and we adopt the abbreviations $\lambda X=\{\lambda\}X$ respectively $\Lambda x=\Lambda \{x\}$ for the particular instances $\lambda \in G, X \subseteq A$ respectively $\Lambda \subseteq G, x \in A$. This by the way defines a canonical action of the monoid $\mathscr{P}(G)$ - monoid under the canonical extension of the multiplication on $G$ to the powerset of $G$ - on the powerset $\mathscr{P}(A)$, as it is easy to prove that for arbitrary subsets $\Lambda, \Pi \subseteq G$ respectively $X \subseteq A$ one has $\left(\Lambda\Pi\right)X=\Lambda\left(\Pi X\right)$ respectively that $1_{\mathscr{P}(G)}X=\left\{1_G\right\}X=X$.

   Consider furthermore an arbitrary operator $\lambda \in G$ and partition $\mathscr{R} \in \mathscr{Part}(A)$; we define the object $\lambda \mathscr{R}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\left\{\lambda X\right\}_{X \in \mathscr{R}}$ and notice that $\lambda \mathscr{R} \in \mathscr{P}(A)$ (try to see if you understand why). Bearing in mind the easily established relations $(\lambda \mu)\mathscr{R}=\lambda\left(\mu \mathscr{R}\right)$ respectively $1_G\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{R}$, valid for any operators $\lambda, \mu \in G$ respectively partition $\mathscr{R} \in \mathscr{Part}(A)$, we realise that the external operation given by:
   $$\begin{align}
   G \times \mathscr{Part}(A) &\to \mathscr{Part}(A) \\
    \left(\lambda, \mathscr{R}\right) &\mapsto \lambda\mathscr{R}
   \end{align}$$
   is an action, namely **the canonical extension of the original action of $G$ on $A$ to the set of partitions $\mathscr{Part}(A)$**.
3. Restricting here our attention solely to an arbitrary group $G$, let us consider its left action of (left) conjugation on itself, for which we will use the special notations ${}^xy\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}xyx^{-1}$ - given $x, y \in G$ - respectively ${}^XY\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\left\{{}^xy\right\}_{\substack{x \in X \\ y \in Y}}$, with the abbreviations $^xY={}^{\{x\}}Y$ respectively $^Xy={}^X\{y\}$ for the particular instances $x \in G, Y \subseteq G$ respectively $X \subseteq G, y \in G$.

Let us mention at this point a highly useful

> **Lemma.** Consider an arbitrary set $A$ and partitions $\mathscr{P}, \mathscr{Q} \in \mathscr{Part}(A)$ such that $\mathscr{P} \subseteq \mathscr{Q}$. Then necessarily $\mathscr{P}=\mathscr{Q}$.

*Proof:* It suffices to show that $\mathscr{Q} \subseteq \mathscr{P}$ and to this end consider arbitrary $Y \in \mathscr{Q}$. We have the relation:
$$Y=Y \cap A=Y \cap \bigcup_{X \in \mathscr{P}} X=\bigcup_{X \in \mathscr{P}}\left(Y \cap X\right),$$
whence - on the grounds that $Y \neq \varnothing$ - we gather there exists $X \in \mathscr{P}$ such that $X \cap Y \neq \varnothing$. However, since $\mathscr{P} \subseteq \mathscr{Q}$ we infer that $X$ and $Y$ are two non-disjoint members of partition $\mathscr{Q}$ and hence $Y=X \in \mathscr{P}$, which concludes the proof. $\Box$

We proceed with a series of propositions.

> **Proposition 1.** Consider the action of a group $G$ on a set $A$, together with an arbitrary subgroup $H \leqslant G$. Then for any operator $\lambda \in G$ we have $\lambda \left(A/H\right)=A/\left({}^{\lambda}H\right)$.

*Proof:* given arbitrary $\lambda \in G$ and $X \in A/H$, there exists by definition an element $x \in A$ such that $X=Hx$, whence $\lambda X=\lambda(Hx)=\left(\lambda H\right)x=\left({}^{\lambda}H\lambda\right)x={}^{\lambda}H\left(\lambda x\right) \in A/\left({}^{\lambda}H\right)$, from which we gather that $\lambda (A/H) \subseteq A/\left({}^{\lambda}H\right)$. Since both members of this inclusion relation are partitions of $A$, the lemma above applies with the conclusion that equality actually takes place. $\Box$

The following corollary is immediate.

> **Corollary 1.** If in addition to the hypotheses of the above proposition we have $H \trianglelefteq G$ (if $H$ is normal), then $A/H$ is *fixed* by the canonical action of $G$ on $\mathscr{Part}(A)$.

Let us remark that given an action of a group $G$ on a set $A$ together with a partition $\mathscr{P} \in \mathscr{Part}(A)$ *fixed* under the canonical action of $G$ on $\mathscr{Part}(A)$ - i.e. a partition such that $\lambda \mathscr{P}=\mathscr{P}$ for all operators $\lambda \in G$ - we can consider the following external operation:
$$\begin{align}
G \times \mathscr{P} &\to \mathscr{P} \\
\left(\lambda, X\right) &\mapsto \lambda X, 
\end{align}$$
which is easily seen to be an action, **the action of $G$ on the blocks of fixed partition $\mathscr{P}$**.

> **Proposition 2.** In the same setting as that of the preceding remark, assume in addition that $G$ acts *transitively* on $A$. Then the canonical action of $G$ on $\mathscr{P}$ is also transitive.

*Proof:* by definition of transitivity, the requirement $\mathscr{P} \neq \varnothing$ must be met and since $\displaystyle\bigcup \mathscr{P}=A \neq \varnothing$ we realise that it is actually met. Given two blocks $X, Y \in \mathscr{P}$, since $X, Y \neq \varnothing$ we infer the existence of $s \in X$ and $t \in Y$. By virtue of the transitivity of $G$'s action on $A$, there exists $\lambda$ such that $\lambda s=t$; since $\lambda X, Y \in \mathscr{P}$ and $t \in Y \cap \lambda X \neq \varnothing$, we infer that $\lambda X=Y$. This concludes the proof. $\Box$

This proposition also has an immediate

> **Corollary 2.** In the same setting of proposition 2 above (a transitive action of a group $G$ on a set $A$ and a partition $\mathscr{P} \in \mathscr{Part}(A)$ fixed by $G$), any two blocks $X, Y \in \mathscr{P}$ are *equipotent*, i.e. they have the same cardinality. If $\mathbf{t}$ denotes the common cardinality of all the blocks in $\mathscr{P}$, the relation $\lvert A \rvert=\left\lvert \mathscr{P} \right\rvert \mathbf{t}$ takes place.

*Proof:* given arbitrary operator $\lambda \in G$ let us introduce
$$\begin{align}
\lambda_A \colon A &\to A \\
\lambda_A(x)&=\lambda x,
\end{align}$$
the map describing the action of the operator $\lambda$. Recall that $\lambda_A$ is a bijection for every $\lambda$; in the particular context of our current corollary, given arbitrary blocks $X, Y \in \mathscr{P}$ we know by virtue of proposition 2 that there exists $\lambda$ such that $Y=\lambda X=\lambda_A[X]$, i.e. $Y$ is the direct image of $X$ through an injection (actually a bijection). By virtue of elementary set theory, this entails the cardinal relation $\lvert X \rvert= \lvert Y \rvert$. As to the final cardinal relation, it is a general property of partitions that $\lvert A \rvert=\displaystyle\sum_{X \in \mathscr{P}}\lvert X \rvert$. In our particular case, bearing in mind that $\lvert X \rvert=\mathbf{t}$ for any $X \in \mathscr{P}$, it follows straight away that $\lvert A \rvert=\displaystyle\sum_{X \in \mathscr{P}}\mathbf{t}=\lvert \mathscr{P} \rvert \mathbf{t}$. $\Box$

In particular we have the following

> **Corollary 3.** Given a *transitive* action of a group $G$ on a set $A$ together with a *normal* subgroup $H \trianglelefteq G$, all the $H$-orbits of $A$ have the same cardinality $\mathbf{t}$ and the relation $\lvert A \rvert=\left\lvert A/H \right\rvert \mathbf{t}$ holds.

*Proof:* this follows directly from corollary 2 above in the special case $\mathscr{P}=A/H$, where we also take into account corollary 1. $\Box$

Corollary 3 above applies to the particular setting of your problem in the following manner: consider an arbitrary group $G$, a given element $t$ and a normal subgroup $H \trianglelefteq G$. The action of $G$ on itself by left conjugation restricts to a *transitive* action of $G$ on the conjugacy class $A={}^Gt$; in particular, one of the $H$-orbits of this set is ${}^Ht$ so the cardinal relation featured in the statement of corollary 3 takes here the particular form $\left\lvert {}^Gt\right\rvert=\left\lvert \left({}^Gt\right)/H \right\rvert \left\lvert {}^Ht\right\rvert$. Under the additional assumption that $G$ is *finite*, all the cardinals featured in this relation are finite - in other words they are natural numbers, at least as far as is concerned the formalisation of mathematics I adhere to - and thus it follows at once that $\left\lvert {}^Ht\right\rvert \mid \left\lvert {}^Gt\right\rvert$.